# How to add red dot badge in table view cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Try to add red dot badge for every unread data in inbox tableviewcell.

I try using cell.accessoryview to add badge

```
        let size: CGFloat = 9
        let width = max(size, 0.7 * size * 1) // perfect circle is smallest allowed
        let badge = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: size))
       
        badge.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2
        badge.layer.masksToBounds = true
        badge.textAlignment = .center
        badge.textColor = UIColor.white
        badge.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        if viewModel.sortedInboxItems[indexPath.section].isRead {
            cell.accessoryView = badge
        }
```

But if using cell.accessoryview it will change the display like image below (TIME in the right corner of the cell is moving forward).  How to make it not change the display?

[image]

**EDIT**

Try to create dot as uilabel in custom uitableview cell like image below

[image]

But the result show like this image below. The red dot shape is not good enough? Can someone help with this issue ?

[image]

Comment: you would need to create a custom cell. Or add the time to the accessory view as well.

Comment: @LeoDabus i've create in inside my own uitableviewcell. But somehow red dot shape is different? can you share your idea how to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accessoryView` is not part of the `contentView` of the cell. If you set the `accessoryView` it will push the `contentView` over to make room for itself. More information on that can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html); this diagram is helpful:

[image: cell structure]

If you don't want it to do this, put your red dot into the cell itself instead of using the `accessoryView`. It's unclear how you've built your cells, but it  looks like you've created a custom `UITableViewCell`, so you should be able to do this without trouble.

Or as commented above, you could include your time label in your accessory view alongside the red dot if applicable.

Comment: I've edit my post. I add my red dot in uitableviewcell (contentview). But somehow the dot result become different. Can you help it ? Is it because it's inside stackview or what?

Comment: Looks like the dot is being squished. You're setting its width and height to different values.

Comment: scaleToFill will change the aspect ration of included views (ie the dot)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `UIView` with corner radius just like you did with the label.  To make sure that the shape is right (sizes have initialised properly) change its corner radius in an overriden `layoutSubviews`.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    badgeInboxView.layer.cornerRadius = badgeInboxView.frame.height/2
}
```